# Storing the previous value and reusing it in a loop

Tags: python

I am implementing a code that after debugging for a month I found out the problem that could be translated in the present simpler case:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    x=2
    if i==1:
        y=2*x
    else:
        y=2*ypred
    
    ypred=y
    print(i)
    print(ypred)
    
    print(y)
```

I want to store only the previous value to be reuse in the loop. However, after analysing the print results, I found out that ypred is not the previous value of y in each interaction but exactly the same.

```
1
4
4
2
8
8
3
16
16
4
32
32
```

I know this problem may be simple, but I am learning how to code for mathematical purposes.
How do I store only the previous value to be reused in the following interaction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @ILS I wanted to reuse the previously stored value, so in the second iteration, it should be 4,8 and not 8,8. The same for the remaining.

Comment: You can move `ypred = y` to the last, but don't forget to initialize `ypred` at the first line.

Comment: @MagnusMoller You are printing `ypred` after `ypred=y` it will always print same value. Just move your print before assigning it to `y` value and it will show you correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving prints in right places leads to this output:

```py
x = 2
ypred = 0
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(f"{i=}")
    print(f"{ypred=}")
    if i == 1:
        y = 2 * x
    else:
        y = 2 * ypred
    print(f"{y=}")
    ypred = y
    print(f"===")
```

Output:

```
i=1
ypred=0
y=4
===
i=2
ypred=4
y=8
===
i=3
ypred=8
y=16
===
i=4
ypred=16
y=32
===
```

Is it desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
ypred=0
for i in range(1,5):
    x=2
    if i==1:
        y=2*x
    else:
        y=2*ypred
    
    print(f"i={i} , ypred= {ypred}, y={y}")
    ypred=y
```

**Output**:

```
i=1 , ypred= 0, y=4
i=2 , ypred= 4, y=8
i=3 , ypred= 8, y=16
i=4 , ypred= 16, y=32
```